# Estimate value of function

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I'm asked:

> For the function $f(x) = x + 1 - \frac{1}{n} , x \in [\frac{n-1}{n},
> > \frac{n}{n+1}]$ in the interval $[0, 1)$.
>
> a) Prove it can be extended by continuity for $x=1$. Call $g$ to that
> new functioon.
>
> b) calculate an upper and a lower estimates for $\int_0^1g$

I really don't know how to start point (a) because $x$ is between those intervals, I believe I cannot simply put $x \rightarrow 1^-$.

The second problem I have is with estimates. What am I supposed to do in order to calculate those estimates? Should I use those intervals $[\frac{n-1}{n},
> \frac{n}{n+1}]$ and multiply the value of supremum/infimum of $g(x)$ there in order to calculate the upper/lower estimates respectively? What would that look like?

Comment: In your function definition there is a stray $\gt$ and the right end should be a round parenthesis to say the interval is open at that end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have continuity at $x=1$ we set $g(x)=x+1$ so that when $n\to\infty$ we have $x\to 1$ and $f(x)\to 2$.

The width of intervals is $$\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n^2+n}$$
We can define Riemann sums considering the left value and the right value of the interval. Left sums give $$s_n=\sum _{k=1}^{n } \left(\frac{k-1}{k}+1\right)\frac{1}{k^2+k}=\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{2 k-1}{k^2 (k+1)}$$
partial fractions $$\frac{2 k-1}{k^2 (k+1)}=3\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)-\frac{1}{k^2}$$
As $n\to\infty$ the first series is a telescoping one and gives $3$, the second is the famous $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, therefore
$$s=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 k-1}{k^2 (k+1)}=3-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\approx 1.355$$
The right sums are
$$S_n=\sum _{k=1}^{n } \left(\frac{k}{k+1}+1\right)\frac{1}{k^2+k}=\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{2 k+1}{k (k+1)^2}$$
like the series above we get
$$S=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 k+1}{k (k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\approx 1.645 $$

Comment: When defining $g$, don't you change the function $f$ behavior by taking out the term $\frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: Indeed we want to extend $f(x)$ such that it is continuous at $x=1$

Answer (score 0):

For a you can show that the low points of each interval converge to a certain value as $x \to 1^-$ and that the limits at the high end also converge to that value.  For b I would note that the low points are all on the curve $y=2x$ and use that for my estimate.  The function sags below that line but the wiggles are fairly small.  You were not asked to assess the error in the estimate.  You could do better by explicitly integrating the first few intervals, which is where most of the error will come from.

Comment: I'm aware that my request is quite unusual... could you take a look at my answer: I am not 100% sure if it makes sense